# How to swap @JsonBackReference and @JsonManagedReference based on which Entity is reference

Tags: java, spring, jackson, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to find a way to swap the @JsonBackRefence and the @JsonManagedReference based on what entity I reference from the associated repository.

**Site.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Site")
public class Site {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="site")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Building> buildings;
}
```

**Building.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "building")
public class Building{

    @Id
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SITE_ID")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Site site;
}
```

**SiteRepository.java**

```
public List<Site> findAll(); //Works as intended
```

**BuildingRepository.java**

```
public Building findById(buildingId); //Works if references are swapped
```

However when calling  findById(buildingId), I want to have the @JsonBackReference swapped. Therefore, the @JsonBackReference is in Site.java and the @JsonManagedReference is in the Building.java entity.

Note: **@JsonIdentityInfo** almosts handles it, but it gives me too much information ie: when I call findById(buildingId) from the BuildingRepository it gives me all the buildings for the site joined to the building found.

Comment: Don't forget to accept/upvote answers that helped you... ;)

Comment: Sorry, had to wait until i was able to test it at work so I could give the proper feedback. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation should help you:

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties("site")
@OneToMany(mappedBy="site")
private List<Building> buildings;

@JsonIgnoreProperties("buildings")
@ManyToOne
private Site site;
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed. I saw the annotation before but didn't know how it worked. I actually thought it would ignore the buildings and site all off time. Thanks so much!