# Three entities mapping is not working properly because of lazy/eager loading in JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I am mapping three entities. Doctor, Client (which extends a Person) and MedicalConsultation.
See my code above. Consider all models class with a default constructor, a constructor with all fields and the getters and setters:

```
@Entity
@Table (name= "person")

public abstract class Person {

@Id @GeneratedValue
protected Long id;
protected String name;
protected String email;
protected String password;

@OneToOne
protected Address address;
```

Now the class Doctor.

```
@Entity(name = "doctor")
public class Doctor extends Person{
@OneToMany(mappedBy="doctor" , fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonManagedReference(value = "job-historical")
private List<MedicalConsultation> medicalConsultations;

@Enumerated
private Type type;

@ElementCollection
private List<String> specialties;
public Doctor() {
        super();
    }

public Doctor(String name, String email, String password, Address address, 
        List<String> specialties, Type type, 
        List<MedicalConsultation> medicalConsultations) {

    super(name,email,password,address);
    this.setMedicalConsultations(medicalConsultations);
    this.setSpecialties(specialties);
    this.setType(type);
}
```

My constructors calls the `super()` and sets their values acording to the super class and its own properties. The same happens with the Client class.

```
@Entity(name = "client")
public class Client extends Person{

    @JsonManagedReference(value = "client-consultations-historical")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="doctor" , fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<MedicalConsultation> medicalConsultations;
```

Here, the Medical Consultation model, which get the other two models

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "medical_consultation")
public class MedicalConsultation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @JsonBackReference(value = "job-historical")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="doctor_fk")
    private Doctor doctor;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="client_fk")
    @JsonBackReference( value = "client-consultations-historical")
    private Client client;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm")
    private Date date;

    private BigDecimal price;
```

Finally, we got the problem:
On my controller class, I cannot get the full data of medicalConsultations. That is, I got the data, the ID and the price, but I do not get the Client and the Doctor for some reason.
But, if I call the method `getDoctor()` or `getClient` and return one of them, I do see all the information.

See the method on the RestControl Class:

```
@RestController
public class Control {

@Autowired
private PersonRepository personRepo;
@Autowired
private ClientRepository clientRepo;
@Autowired
private AddressRepository addressRepo;
@Autowired
private DoctorRepository doctorRepo;
@Autowired
private MedicalConsultationRepository consultationRepo;
@GetMapping("consultations")
    public List<MedicalConsultation> getConsultations() {
        List<MedicalConsultation> consultations = this.consultationRepo.findAll();
        return consultations;
    }
```

Maybe there is something wrong on the Mapping. But I set the hibernate to show the sql, and it apparently makes all the query getting everything that I want. See:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        medicalcon0_.id as id1_2_,
        medicalcon0_.client_fk as client_f4_2_,
        medicalcon0_.date as date2_2_,
        medicalcon0_.doctor_fk as doctor_f5_2_,
        medicalcon0_.price as price3_2_ 
    from
        medical_consultation medicalcon0_
Hibernate: 
    select
        client0_.id as id2_3_0_,
        client0_.address_id as address_7_3_0_,
        client0_.email as email3_3_0_,
        client0_.name as name4_3_0_,
        client0_.password as password5_3_0_,
        address1_.id as id1_0_1_,
        address1_.city as city2_0_1_,
        address1_.number as number3_0_1_,
        address1_.phone as phone4_0_1_,
        address1_.street as street5_0_1_,
        medicalcon2_.doctor_fk as doctor_f5_2_2_,
        medicalcon2_.id as id1_2_2_,
        medicalcon2_.id as id1_2_3_,
        medicalcon2_.client_fk as client_f4_2_3_,
        medicalcon2_.date as date2_2_3_,
        medicalcon2_.doctor_fk as doctor_f5_2_3_,
        medicalcon2_.price as price3_2_3_,
        client3_.id as id2_3_4_,
        client3_.address_id as address_7_3_4_,
        client3_.email as email3_3_4_,
        client3_.name as name4_3_4_,
        client3_.password as password5_3_4_ 
    from
        person client0_ 
    left outer join
        address address1_ 
            on client0_.address_id=address1_.id 
    left outer join
        medical_consultation medicalcon2_ 
            on client0_.id=medicalcon2_.doctor_fk 
    left outer join
        person client3_ 
            on medicalcon2_.client_fk=client3_.id 
    where
        client0_.id=? 
        and client0_.dtype='client'
Hibernate: 
    select
        doctor0_.id as id2_3_0_,
        doctor0_.address_id as address_7_3_0_,
        doctor0_.email as email3_3_0_,
        doctor0_.name as name4_3_0_,
        doctor0_.password as password5_3_0_,
        doctor0_.type as type6_3_0_,
        address1_.id as id1_0_1_,
        address1_.city as city2_0_1_,
        address1_.number as number3_0_1_,
        address1_.phone as phone4_0_1_,
        address1_.street as street5_0_1_,
        medicalcon2_.doctor_fk as doctor_f5_2_2_,
        medicalcon2_.id as id1_2_2_,
        medicalcon2_.id as id1_2_3_,
        medicalcon2_.client_fk as client_f4_2_3_,
        medicalcon2_.date as date2_2_3_,
        medicalcon2_.doctor_fk as doctor_f5_2_3_,
        medicalcon2_.price as price3_2_3_,
        client3_.id as id2_3_4_,
        client3_.address_id as address_7_3_4_,
        client3_.email as email3_3_4_,
        client3_.name as name4_3_4_,
        client3_.password as password5_3_4_ 
    from
        person doctor0_ 
    left outer join
        address address1_ 
            on doctor0_.address_id=address1_.id 
    left outer join
        medical_consultation medicalcon2_ 
            on doctor0_.id=medicalcon2_.doctor_fk 
    left outer join
        person client3_ 
            on medicalcon2_.client_fk=client3_.id 
    where
        doctor0_.id=? 
        and doctor0_.dtype='doctor'
```

Can Someone tell me what is happing?

Comment: where is your MedicalConsultation entiy? show us the MedicalConsultation so we understand how you map them

Comment: sorry. I have forgotten it.

Comment: in `MedicalConsultation` for `Client` and `Doctor`, set the fetchtype in the `@ManyToOne` to eager and see if that works. (i.e. `@ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` )

Comment: I forgot to tell that I have already tryed it. And it has not worked.

Comment: Have you tried to remove `@JsonBackReference(value = "job-historical")` and `@JsonBackReference( value = "client-consultations-historical")`? It won't serialize the Client or the Doctor because of that.

Comment: I had another problem which was solve using these anotations. As you can see above, I got a two way relationship and when I tried to get all elements ( clients, doctors and/or medical consultations) I gets into a infinite loop. That is, if I tried to get all clients, it would try to get the medical consultations of this client, which has a client inside, which has medical consultations.... Got it?

Comment: Yes I was aware of this. I wasn't sure if every ways were called. Maybe this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47721145/how-to-swap-jsonbackreference-and-jsonmanagedreference-based-on-which-entity-i) is going to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

try you mapping annotation like bellow on MedicalConsultation.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Doctor doctor;
```

Comment: I forgot to tell that I have already tryed it. And it has not worked.

Comment: I have tried to consume it with typescript and I got a error saying that it is not possible to read the property "person". Maybe here I got the problem